# Turning off Galaxy S4 while charging

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, charging

I manually upgraded my Galaxy S4 to Kitkat; since it was rooted, upgrade couldn't be done automatically. It was successfully done but thereafter my phone turns on automatically whenever a charger is connected.

I sometimes prefer turning off my phone while charging (to make it charge faster). This is impossible now. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes,to make it faster. Thanks. Guess, I'll settle for the airplane.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to charge your phone faster without turning it off (due to the update), then you can simply:

- Turn on airplane mode
- Turn off WiFi, mobile data, and GPS

After that, it will charge just as fast as if your phone is off. If it's not charging, the battery level doesn't change for hours, unless you actually turn on the screen.